# How to rename a column/proprety within fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, renaming

Say I already have a Table:

### Customer

First
Last

Thus I would have an object with properties such as:

Customer.First
Customer.Last

If I wanted to refactor the code so that I rename the properties:

Customer.FirstName
Customer.LastName

Is there a way to indicate to NHibernate to update First to FirstName and so on?

I already know how to update using SchemaUpdate, but it just adds those two properties as new columns.  Is there a way to indicate to re-map?

Thanks,

Gally

Answer (score 0):

Use a DB migration tool for that. [Here's a list of options](http://flux88.com/blog/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/) for doing database migrations in .NET